# Linq to NHibernate + transformations + futures

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, future

I know you can execute a Linq to NHibernate query as a future by calling the .ToFuture<>() extension method. However I'm not loading mapped entities but directly loading the data into DTO's. So you get something like:

```
var results = (from e in session.Query<Entity>()
               where e.Reference.Id == someId
               orderby e.Name
               select new Dto
               {
                   Id = e.Id,
                   Name = e.Name,
                   // ...
               }).ToFuture<Dto>();
```

This doesn't work as I want it (I dare to say *expected*). I now get an error: `The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "Entity" and cannot be used in this generic collection.` If I remove `.ToFuture()` it does work, but the query is not batched.

I know you can do this with the QueryOver API, I just like Linq to NH better because it's so much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug. If you can create a simple reproduction test case, please enter a new issue at https://nhibernate.jira.com/.

Before doing that, please verify if you're using the latest version (3.2 at the time), as there was already a [similar defect](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2690) that was fixed in this release.

Comment: That's probably it then. I'm using NHibernate 3.0 (common library restriction :-( which is probably the problem here. I can't easily test with 3.2 though. I'll switch to QueryOver then...